# Pagination error suddenly appearing

Tags: pagination, ab-pagination

Overnight the following php error is being reported on our EE (2.6) site for pages requiring pagination:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Pagination_object::$pager_sql

Filename: ab_pagination/ext.ab_pagination.php

Line Number: 159
```

e.g. here:

http://www.tutor2u.net/blog/index.php/business-studies/

Any thoughts on why + how to fix?

Jim

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the error is coming from the [AB Pagination](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-pagination) add-on. Have you updated it recently?

As to why it's suddenly appearing, it's possible that the error may have always been there and it just wasn't shown. Maybe the server it's hosted on has had it's PHP `error_reporting` settings changed in it's INI file to allow PHP Notices to be visible?

This [blog post](http://bncscripts.com/blog/149/how-to-hide-php-notice-warning-messages/) tells you how you can turn errors and notices on/off in code. So you would put the code it suggests in the `ab_pagination/ext.ab_pagination.php` file.

**However**, I'd suggest getting to the root of why the error is being caused in the first place, rather than putting a sticking plaster over it. I notice you've asked the question over at [Addon Bakery](https://getsatisfaction.com/addonbakery/topics/pagination_error_has_appeared), so hopefully the developer will give you a satisfactory answer.